# persists data in the datatable between postbacks in java( I am working in spring framework)

Tags: java

When I display searched datas in the datatable and clicking a link in the datatable goes to another page and when I click the Browser back button It asks for resubmission.(ie; Resend).
I need to stay back in the datatables page from where I have clicked the link.

Answer (score 0):

It's considered a good practice to follow the Redirect-after-POST pattern when submitting forms so that you can avoid the "Confirm Form Resubmission" case whenever the user presses the Back button.

I'm not familiar with how Spring MVC works, but the basic idea is, after the user submits the form and you process it, you redirect the user to the next url, which could be a success page, for example.

Here are some SO questions that might provide you with examples specifically for Spring MVC:

- [Spring - Redirect after POST (even with validation errors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543797/spring-redirect-after-post-even-with-validation-errors)
- [Spring 3.1 MVC - Form handling workflow best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313919/spring-3-1-mvc-form-handling-workflow-best-practice?lq=1)