# Spring MVC front-end choosing a form action target

Tags: java, html, user-interface, spring-mvc

My web application has a number of forms, the simplest of which is the login form (I'm using thymeleaf):

```
    <form method="post" action = "#" th:action = "@{/account/login}">
        Username: <input name="username" type="text" /> <br /> 
        Password: <input name="password" type="password" /> <br /> 
                  <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

My controller handler method for this is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "login")
public String login(@RequestParam("username") String username, 
        @RequestParam("password") String password,
        Model model) {

    // do some logging in           
    return "/account/profile";
}
```

My problem with this is that because I'm doing a POST to `/account/login`, that's what's showing up in browser address bar. I really want it show `/account/profile`. Should I instead be doing a POST to `/account/profile` even though conceptually it isn't correct.

Another solution is to do POST on `/account/login` and, after success, redirect and do a GET on `/account/profile`.

Assuming I also have such a handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() {
    return "/account/login";
}
```

What are some other solutions that might fit the concept of REST-like url mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a redirect after POST is what fits your need most:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() {
    return "redirect:/account/profile";
}
```

The advantage of that approach (comparing to the current way - returning the view right in the action), is that if user press "F5", the form will not get re-posted. This has become a pattern: [redirect after post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

If you are wondering about how to show error after redirecting, [Spring 3.1 support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543797/spring-redirect-after-post-even-with-validation-errors).

P/s: Actually, the link to process have no relation with what show up on user's browser address bar. If you only concern about the URL, you can use "url-rewriting" libraries, such as [Turkey URLRewriter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)