# "${#fields.hasErrors('*')}" always false - Redirect Problem

Tags: forms, validation, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My controller looks like this:

```
    @PostMapping("/event/{id}")
    public String save(@PathVariable("id") long id, @Valid Form form, BindingResult bindingResult ) {

        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
          //No errors
          //No return
        }

        return "redirect:/event/{id}";               
    }
```

My @GetMapping is:

```
 @GetMapping("/event/{id}")
    public ModelAndView eventDetail(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("event/details");
        Event event = eventoRepository.findById(id).get();
        model.addObject("event", evento);
        model.addObject("guests", event.getGuests());
        model.addObject("guest",new Guest());

        return model;

    }
```

I know that "${#fields.hasErrors('*')}" is always false because redirect. (right?)

How return to  this path `/event/{id}` without redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that "${#fields.hasErrors('*')}" is always false because redirect. (right?)

Right. It looks like you always redirect. Because of that a method annotated with `@GetMapping("/event/{id}")` is called, the form most likely is reseted to fresh state and there are no more errors making expression always `false`.

> How return to this path /event/{id} without redirect?

Simply return name of the view (template) containing the form. Most likely it's the same what's returned by method annotated with `@GetMapping("/event/{id}")`.

You should follow an approach from [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/). Return without redirect if the form contains error, and redirect otherwise.

**Edit:** 
You should also provide additional objects to the model. Instead of populating model in each method (Get, Post etc.) you may extract common objects to a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute`. According to [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) such a method can accept similar parameters as methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`.

For your case something like this should work fine:

```java
    @ModelAttribute
    void supplyModel(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {
        Event event = eventoRepository.findById(id).get();
        model.addAttribute("event", evento);
        model.addAttribute("guests", event.getGuests());
        model.addAttribute("guest",new Guest());
    }

    @GetMapping("/event/{id}")
    public String eventDetail(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        return "event/details";

    }

    @PostMapping("/event/{id}")
    public String save(@PathVariable("id") long id, @Valid Form form, BindingResult bindingResult ) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            // Has errors
            return "event/details";
        }

        // No errors
        return "redirect:/event/" + id;
    }
```

Comment: If I return direct to my template, I lost my models to render my template. My @GetMapping to "event/{id} add some models necessary to render my page. If I return direct to my template some data in my page will be blank.

Comment: I add @GetMapping in my original post

Comment: @GlaucoTodesco I've updated my answer. Hope it resolves your issue. Cheers!