# Spring MVC forward to new URL keeping existing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to redirect to a previous page is a domain object is invalid. For example with a domain object of Address.

```
@Autowired 
private Address address;
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addressPage(
  ModelMap model
) throws StdAddFault {
  model.addAttribute("address", address);
  return TILE_GET_STARTED_ADDRESS;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String selectAddress(
  @Valid Address address,
  BindingResult result,
  Model model,
  HttpSession session
) throws StdAddFault {
  if(result.hasErrors()) {
    model.addAttribute("address", address);
    return "/address";
  }
  ...
}
```

Problem is after the request instead of being /address it is /address/validate. This seems a little misleading but if i use a redirect or a forward i lose my information.

Is there any way to make the url after the contoller /address (for invalid data only)?

**Update**

I confirmed the above does not work. This does work but I am concerned one request may overwrite another's Address. Is this a valid concern?

```
if(result.hasErrors()) {
  this.address = address;
  return "redirect:/get-started/address";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you loose your information on redirect? Usually if you add them to the model and then redirect they stay.

Comment: I will double check and confirm. I got it to work using this.address=address and a redirect but I am not sure how this will work in production. For example if multiple requests are sent does each one have an instance or will one instance overwrite another.

Comment: You could add your address object as an attribute of the request and use forward, this will keep alive that object and then in the Controller for "/validate" get that address from the request Object

Comment: What about the session? Maybe I could store it there?

Comment: As far as i now the forward sends exactly the same request over the controllers so the session will remain there and you will have your address attribute on the request.

Comment: Didn't work for me, also I need to use the redirect so the url changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I finally went with

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/address")
public class AddressController {
  private String getMainPage(
    ModelMap model,
    HttpSession session
  ){
    if(!model.containsAttribute("address"))
      model.addAttribute("address", new Address());
...
    return TILE_GET_STARTED_ADDRESS;
}

@RequestMapping(value = URL_ADDRESS_SELECT, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validateAddress(
  @Valid Address address,
  BindingResult result,
  Model model,
  RedirectAttributes attr,
  HttpSession session
) throws StdAddFault {
  if(result.hasErrors()) {
    attr.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.address", result);
    attr.addFlashAttribute("address", address);
    return "redirect:/address";
  }
  ....
}
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543797/spring-redirect-after-post-even-with-validation-errors) question + you guys helped me out a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're after is an "address" model attribute stored in session. This will retain unique address object per user-session

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"address"})
@RequestMapping("/address")
public class AddressController {

  /**
   * Injected model reference will contain 'address' if it exists in session
   */
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String addressPage(Model model) {
    if(!model.containsAttribute("address"))
      model.addAttribute("address", new Address());
    return "address";
  }

  /**
   * This handler maps to form selecting / updating the address object
   * at the end of this method the address object is automatically
   * stored in session
   */
  @RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String selectAddress(@ModelAttribute("address") Address address) {
    // do stuff with the newly updated address..
  }
}
```

If in any other handler you need the address object, all you need to do is just inject `@ModelAttribute("address") Address address` on the argument

Comment: What about the errors if there are some. Since they are in the BindingResult. Is there a way to still pass these?

Comment: Also how do I use the @valid annotation for validation

Comment: Sure binding error will still work as per Spring doc. Sorry using @Valid annotation is out of scope from your question, please find another thread, I'm sure it has been asked many times before.

Comment: So how would I propagate the error messages from the binding result?

Answer (score 0):

I can do it one of 2 ways but I am not sure which one to use..

1.)

```
if(result.hasErrors()) {
  this.address=address;
  return "redirect:/get-started/address";
}
```

My concerns here revolve around object lifecycle using the Autowired. Could one call overwrite the address on another?

The other option is to use session...

```
private String getMainPage(
  ModelMap model,
  HttpSession session
){
  if(session.getAttribute("address") == null){
    session.setAttribute("address", new Address());
  }
  model.addAttribute("mainNav", MAIN_NAV);
  model.addAttribute("subNav", SUB_NAV);
  model.addAttribute("address", session.getAttribute("address"));
  return TILE_GET_STARTED_ADDRESS;
}
```

I would really like to avoid the session though.

Comment: I think that if you do the first approach you will overwrite the address because the class is instantiated only once so after the first request if it had some error on the result that will overwrite the Address

Comment: Other thing that you could change is set the scope of the Bean of Address to prototype so everytime the request is made it will give you a new Address obj

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Comment: Also my Error messages don't seem to get passed

Comment: The ones in BindingResult?

Comment: Rt but how do I propogate down the BindingResult?

Comment: Try adding all the parameters to the addressPage controller and then forward it to selectAddress to see if they are Added but it is supposed to be the same request between the two controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok to get a new Object each time make your Controller implement BeanFactoryAware.

Then implement the method setBeanFactory something like this.

```
private Address address.

public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory context) {
     address = (Address)context.getBean("myAddress");
  }
```

So everytime you call setBeanFactory this will get an Address object and because of the scope = prototype it will be a new object.