# Spring MVC validation doesn't show error message

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I'm working on web application which should validate date before save it in DB. So i'm trying to use for that spring mvc validator. But I have a problem that form doesn't show error message.

My user.jsp:

```
<form:form class="editUser" method="POST" commandName="user">
    <form:input path="email"/>
    <form:errors path="email"/>
    other fields
</form>
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") final User user,
        BindingResult result) throws Exception
{
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "redirect:/addUser";
    } else {
        handler.saveUser(user);
        return "redirect:/userList";
   }
}
```

My User class:

```
public class User {
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your email addresss.")
    private String email;

    other fields
}
```

As far as I see in debug mode result contains error if I submit empty email, but it error doesn't show on page. Could some one help me?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried to use `RedirectAttributes`, but it still doesn't work.

My controller:

```
public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") final User user,
        BindingResult result) throws Exception
{
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.user", result);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errors", result.getAllErrors());
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("user", user);
        return "redirect:/addUser";
    } else {
        handler.saveUser(user);
        return "redirect:/userList";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't** `redirect` in case of validation failed.

sample code:

```
public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") final User user,
        BindingResult result) throws Exception
{
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addUser";
    } else {
        handler.saveUser(user);
        return "redirect:/userList";
   }
}
```

Comment: But i have to, because my JSP is addUser.jsp and save method is mapped in addUser/save, so if i just use "addUser" it will be wrong behaviour. I have tried to use `RedirectAttributes`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: simply forward the request to the same page.

Comment: you can check this related question, it might provide an answer - perhaps your form is being reinitialised in the redirect, or using ModelAndView... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543797/spring-redirect-after-post-even-with-validation-errors