# Spring validator: How to redirect on the form page by displaying the input errors with the data of the select fields?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to display the errors of a spring form with a redirection on the form page but nothing. But the errors appear when I do `return formpage`. However this method does not display the data of the select fields

```java
if (!result.hasErrors()) {
    cylindreService.createCylindre(cylindre);
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute(
                            "success",
                            "Cylindre " + cylindre.getNumgma() + " à été ajouté avec succès"
    );
    return "redirect:/cylindre/listes";
}
return "redirect:/cylindre/add";
```

Comment: The errors don't survive  the redirect. So either don't redirect on errors or handle as for success: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543797/spring-redirect-after-post-even-with-validation-errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring - Redirect after POST (even with validation errors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543797/spring-redirect-after-post-even-with-validation-errors)